# Na hora da impressão, é adicionada páginas em branco

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, impressão

Na hora de imprimir minha página, esta sendo adicionada páginas em branco, o número destas páginas é relativo, às vezes 1, 2...
Já tentei soluções como:

```
  .print:last-child {
       page-break-after: auto;
    }

    html, body { 
       height: auto; 
    } 

   .print{
       page-break-after: always
    }
```

E não funcionou, no `CSS` eu uso uma configuração de colunas para o `Bootstrap` funcionar também não impressão

```
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
}

.col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
}

.col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
}

.col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
}

.col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
}

.col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
}

.col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
}

.col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
}

.col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
}

.col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
}

.col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
}

.col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
}

.col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

Sem essas configurações de `col`, elas não ficam alinhadas no print como ficam na tela.

Como posso fixar este "Bug"?

Comment: Só a última página impressa ou a cada 1 página a próxima sai em branco?
Você tentou mudar configurações de margens? O conteúdo impresso muda muito ou é fixo? Quando visualiza a impressão aparece corretamente?

Comment: A impressão mostra normalmente, só sai com páginas extras em branco, dependendo do tamanho do conteúdo, aumenta o numero de pagina em branco. Ex: o conteúdo para impressão ocupa 2 paginas, mas aparece mais 2 em brancos totalizando 4

Comment: Faça um teste, veja o que acontece se você trocar no `.print:last-child` o valor de `page-break-after:` de **auto** para **avoid**, tente **always** também para ver se muda algo.

Comment: Estava alterando as configurações de impressão do próprio browser e em margens consigo remover as paginas em brancos, alterando para Minima ou Nenhuma, ou seja, esta muito relativo o tipo que devo usar na config para retirar as paginas em branco, as vezes um remove (Nenhuma por exemplo)e as vezes somente a outra remove.

Comment: Pena que é muito difícil analisar, sinto que deve ser algo bem simples, mas o problema está muito abstrato aos nossos olhos! Poste um código completo (html gerado) dessa página para que possamos testar aqui também e tentar ver onde está o problema! Em um caso extremo onde eu não consigo através de debug (navegador) avaliar a disposição dos objetos ou seu comportamente, eu coloco BORDAS para visualizar se algum elemento está sobrepondo outro ou se tem algo anormal!